# Gerrit init doesn't prompt me for the database type

Tags: database, postgresql, gerrit

why doesn't prompt me the Gerrit's init for the database type?

I am using the latest release (3.4.0) from Gerrit.

KI

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit no longer supports SQL databases. The data is stored directly in the git repository instead.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/note-db.html